# Не получается спарсить страницу

Tags: php

Не получается спарсить страницу, пробовал через file_get_contents и curl, на выходе результат всегда один:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
function eraseCookieFromAllPaths(name) { 
var pathBits = location.pathname.split("/");var pathCurrent = " path=";document.cookie = name + "=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;";for (var i = 0; i < pathBits.length; i++) {pathCurrent += ((pathCurrent.substr(-1) != "/") ? "/" : "") + pathBits[i];
document.cookie = name + "=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;" + pathCurrent + ";";}}
eraseCookieFromAllPaths("BHC");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() { 
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) { 
var a=xmlhttp.responseText;document.cookie="BHC="+a+"; path=/";document.location.href="/"; } };
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/banhammer/pid", true);xmlhttp.send();
</script>
</body></html>
```

Может кто-нибудь поможет советом?

Comment: а ожидается то что?

Comment: И при чем здесь PHP, когда вы пытаетесь достать код через XmlHttpRequest посредством AJAX запроса?

Comment: Я разве говорю про AJAX? У меня такое выводится после простейшего примера с использованием file_get_contents. А мне нужно получать код страницы с которым можно дальше работать.

Comment: судя по всему там какая-то защита от DDoS или от скачивания контента ботами. Формируется какой-то ajax запрос. Можете попробовать использовать что-то вроде phantomjs, чтобы выполнить javascript при парсинге